# Android Studio, Cannot resolve symbol 'NonNull', import androidx.annotation.NonNull; is causing the problem

Tags: java, android-studio, kotlin

I have imported NonNull with import androidx.annotation.NonNull;, however it brings up the error Cannot resolve symbol 'NonNull', my build.gradle already has implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.6.0'

I tried implementing implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.6.0' in my build.gradle, and I tried migrating to androidx, I also invalidated the caches, and tried many other variations of import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
I also rebuilt, and cleaned the project multiple times.

This error has repeated in the following:

```
import androidx.annotation.RawRes;
import androidx.annotation.SdkConstant;
import androidx.annotation.SdkConstant.SdkConstantType;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have already imported the `androidx.annotation.NonNull` package and added the `implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.6.0'` dependency in your `build.gradle` file, but you are still getting the error "Cannot resolve symbol 'NonNull'," there are a few possible solutions you can try:

1. Make sure you have the latest version of the Android Gradle Plugin and AndroidX annotations. You can check for updates by going to your project's `build.gradle` file and verifying that you have the latest versions specified. For example:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2' // Make sure this version is up to date
    }
}

...

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.6.0' // Make sure this version is up to date
}
```

2. Clean and rebuild your project. Sometimes, stale or cached files can cause issues. Go to `Build > Clean Project` in Android Studio and then `Build > Rebuild Project` to ensure a clean build.
3. Check for any conflicting dependencies. In your `build.gradle` file, make sure there are no other dependencies that might conflict with the `androidx.annotation` package. Remove any duplicates or conflicting dependencies.
4. Verify that your import statements are correct. Double-check your import statements in your code to ensure that you are importing the correct package. The correct import statement for `NonNull` should be:

```java
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
```

5. Check if you are using the correct annotation. The `@NonNull` annotation is part of the AndroidX annotations library. If you are using it for Kotlin code, make sure you import `kotlin-annotations` instead of `androidx.annotation`. Add the following dependency to your `build.gradle` file:

```
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-annotations:1.4.10' // Make sure this version is up to date
```

If none of these solutions work, there might be a more specific issue with your project setup or configuration. You can provide more details about your project structure and the specific error messages you are encountering for further assistance.

Comment: Whenever I click rebuild project I get many errors, here is an example:
Gradle Sync issues
Could not find androidx.core:core-ktx:1.10.01.
Required by:
    project :app
Search in build.gradle files
In my build.gradle file I wrote
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.10.01'
Also thank you very much for responding